# How to search in jQuery DataTable column?

Tags: jquery, search, filter, datatable

I would like to determine whether a particular string appears in a column in a jQuery DataTable, but I couldn't find a straightforward way of doing this. Am I missing an easy way to go about this?

The `.fnFilter()` function is almost what I want, except, it filters the table directly, whereas I want to the filtered row(s) to return as results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of plug-in API functions available: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api, in particular the `fnFindCellRowIndexes()` and `fnFindCellRowNodes()`